# Вопрос по наследованию Java

Tags: java

Пишу примитивный "морской бой", есть два класса - UserMonitor(поле игрока с его кораблями) и BattleMonitor(поле боя).

```
public class UserMonitor {
    private String name;
    private char[][] field;
    
    public UserMonitor(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void showField(){}
    public void setShip(){}
    public void getPosition(){}
    public void setPosition(){}
}
    
public class BattleMonitor {
    private String name;
    private char[][] field;

    public UserMonitor(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void showField(){}
    public void getPosition(){}
    public void setPosition(){}
}
```

Поскольку у них много общего решил сделать для них общий класс Monitor. Но не знаю как быть с private полями. Если вынести в общий, то придётся делать public, иначе не будет доступа у наследников, но доступ нужен так как нужно будет оперировать элементами массива в методах наследников. Подскажите как лучше это организовать, так как пишу подобное первый раз и хочется все делать правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Ваше стремление сделать общий класс Monitor в данном случае правильное. Для доступа к полям родительского класса следует использовать модификатор доступа `protected` у полей родительского класса.

```
public abstract class Monitor {
 protected String name;
 protected char[][] field;
...
}
```

Хорошим решением будет сделать этот класс `abstract`. В абстрактном классе можно также определить поля и методы, но нельзя создать объект или экземпляр. Это применимо, поскольку в Вашей реализации могут использоваться экземпляры либо `UserMonitor`, либо `BattleMonitor`, но потребности в создании классов обычного `Monitor` нет.

Comment: Но ведь с модификатором protected остаётся доступ к полям не только у наследников но и у классов из того же пакета. У меня в проекте всего 4-5 классов, стоит ли создавать пакет для ограничения видимости? И на счет абстрактного класса, на пример у наследника BattleMonitor есть метод setShip, которого нет у UserMonitor, в таком случае этот метод нужно определять в абстрактном классе или только в BatleMonitor? И стоит ли делать общий класс абстрактным, если я не могу выделить абстрактные методы(так как общие методы имеют одну и ту же реализацию)?

Comment: Если Вам требуется ограничить доступ к полям класса у классов из того же пакета, то создайте отдельный пакет. В классе Monitor вы можете указать методы, которые есть у всех его наследников. getName(), showField(), getPosition(), setPosition(). Кроме этого в данном конкретном примере следует реализовать метод getName() как default. Этим вы избавите себя от реализации этого метода в каждом из классов-наследников. Аналогично можно поступить и с другими методами класса. Абстрактный класс как раз-таки Вам позволяет решить проблему с одинаковой реализацией методов во всех классах-наследниках.

Comment: спасибо, вы мне очень помогли)